# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable was corrupted C++

Tags: c++, stack, runtime, corruption

Here is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo.h>

typedef struct A
{

friend class W;

private:
        char c;
        void *v;
} A;

typedef struct LL
{

friend class W;

private:
        int n;
        LL *next, *prev;
} LL;

class W
{

private:
        void Handle(void *arg1, void *arg2)
        {
                A *ob1 = reinterpret_cast<A*>(arg1);
                ob1->c = 'c';
                ob1->v = (void*)0xffffffff;

                LL *ob2 = reinterpret_cast<LL*>(arg2);
                ob2->n = 0xff;
                ob2->next = new LL();
                ob2->prev = 0;
        }

protected:
        void Set()
        {
                A *ob1 = new A();
                LL *ob2 = new LL();

                this->Handle(&ob1, &ob2);
        }
};

class R : W
{

public:
        R(void)
        {
                this->Set();
        }
};

void main(void)
{
        R *ob = new R();
}
```

I'm getting the next result from dump:
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ob2' was corrupted.

'http.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\root\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\http\Debug\http.exe'
, Symbols loaded.
'http.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'
'http.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'
'http.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'
'http.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_bb1f6aa1308c35eb\msvcr90d.dll'
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ob2' was corrupted.

**My quesions are:**
 *- What should I do to solve this problem?

 - Why I have got such error, can you describe me, why its was exaclty corrupted?

 - And why the Stack is corrupted? not the heap?*

Thanks,
Best regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A *ob1 = new A();
LL *ob2 = new LL();

this->Handle(&ob1, &ob2);
```

`ob1` and `ob2` are already pointers. By taking the addresses of the variables (of types, respectively, `A**` and `LL**`), then passing them to `Handle` where they are hammered into `A*` and `LL*` with `reinterpret_cast`s and then written to, the code invokes undefined behaviour. In this particular case it appears to be writing to locations near the `ob1` and `ob2` variables, which are probably on the stack frame of a call to `Set`.

If instead of butchering the type system with `reinterpret_cast`, the code used it properly, the compiler would have caught the error immediately:

```
void Handle(A *arg1, LL *arg2)
{
        ob1->c = 'c';
        ob1->v = (void*)0xffffffff;

        ob2->n = 0xff;
        ob2->next = new LL();
        ob2->prev = 0;
}

// ...
// the compiler would complain about this call making the problem clear
this->Handle(&ob1, &ob2);
```

It would be even better if the code didn't use so many pointers all over the place, but I'm going to assume this was just a simple piece of code to demonstrate the problem.